# Wordpress Bootstrap carosel image not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building my Wordpress theme with Bootstrap and am using a carousel on my front page right below the navbar. I found a great way to loop through the images here  [1]: http://www.lanexa.net/2012/04/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-display-wordpress-dynamic-content/

I wanted to run a test on one of the slider areas so I put in the code for the first loop and it displays the title and the excerpt but my image does not show up at all. How can I fix this issue and what is a good way to loop through the rest of the images in the carousel. I added the second loop with the code I found in the link and it messed up my page so I took it out. Here is what I have so far still with some static content that I want to loop through as well. I am going to have 3 images going in the carousel. This is my first real project with Wordpress as I am trying to build my portfolio theme so any help is appreciated!

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

   <?php
     $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'category_name'  => 'Home Carousel',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
     ));
     while ($the_query->have_posts() ) :
      $the_query->the_post();
      $attachment_ids[] = get_the_ID();
     endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php foreach($attachment_ids as $attachment_id_k=>$attachment_id_v ){ 
        if($attachment_id_k == 0){$class_active = 'class="active"';}
        else{$class_active = 'class=""';}
        ?>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" <?php echo $class_active;?> data-slide-to="<?php echo $attachment_id_k;?>"></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php foreach($attachment_ids as $attachment_id_k=>$attachment_id_v ){ 
        if($attachment_id_k == 0){$class_active = 'class="item active"';}
        else{$class_active = 'class="item"';}
        ?>
    <div <?php echo $class_active;?>>
        <div class="display_table">
            <div class="display_table_cell">
            <?php 
            $default_attr = array(
                'class' => "gallery_images",
                'alt'   => 'Gallery Images',
            );
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id_v, 'full', 1, $default_attr );
            $image_data = get_post( $attachment_id_v );
            if($image_data->post_excerpt != ''){
            ?>
            <div class="carousel-caption my_caption">
                <p><?php echo $image_data->post_excerpt;?></p>
            </div>
            <?php }?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: Is it in `noConflict` mode? WordPress and jQuery rarely get along off the bat.

Comment: Ok I will look into that. That may be part of the issue. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Would I add in something like this in my js file? `code` $ = jQuery.noConflict(true); `code`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ should give you all you need regarding jQuery's noConflict function. You just have to wrap your jQuery in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the Working Code !!!**

First through the while loop get all the post IDS in an array

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name'  => 'Home Carousel',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
));
while ($the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    $attachment_ids[] = get_the_ID();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Now through the array `$attachment_ids` get the carousel working

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php foreach($attachment_ids as $attachment_id_k=>$attachment_id_v ){ 
            if($attachment_id_k == 0){$class_active = 'class="active"';}
            else{$class_active = 'class=""';}
            ?>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" <?php echo $class_active;?> data-slide-to="<?php echo $attachment_id_k;?>"></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php foreach($attachment_ids as $attachment_id_k=>$attachment_id_v ){ 
            if($attachment_id_k == 0){$class_active = 'class="item active"';}
            else{$class_active = 'class="item"';}
            ?>
        <div <?php echo $class_active;?>>
            <div class="display_table">
                <div class="display_table_cell">
                <?php 
                $default_attr = array(
                    'class' => "gallery_images",
                    'alt'   => 'Gallery Images',
                );
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id_v, 'full', 1, $default_attr );
                $image_data = get_post( $attachment_id_v );
                if($image_data->post_excerpt != ''){
                ?>
                <div class="carousel-caption my_caption">
                    <p><?php echo $image_data->post_excerpt;?></p>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

put this javascript code at footer.php, since its bootstrap carousel so need some javascript to set the options

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 3000
})
</script>
```

Comment: Wow this is great but I still can not get the carousel to work. I edited my code above to reflect the new changes. Is my new WP_Query in the wrong place?

Comment: would I need to add theme support for the carousel?

Comment: I still cannot get the carousel to work. Do I need to enqueue  jQuery in my functions.php? Or is it already included with Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

In your code item section you write

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
```

but I found that in that tutorial link they used

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('large');?>.
```

Can you check it. Is this the reason for your error ?

Comment: I tried to plug in some of the other values and they didn't work either. I think the parameter has to be set according to the image size that is used but I'm not sure since I'm still new to Wordpress.